# WSO2 MB vs Apache Kafka

Tags: wso2, apache-kafka, messagebroker, wso2-message-broker, wso2-cep

I've been working with both `Apache Kafka` plus `WSO2 Message Broker` in order to publish and consume messages using `Topics`. But then apart from changing the `jndi` properties in WSO2 MB, the configurations in integrating the `WSO2 CEP` looks to be the same in both.

I'm sure it has it's own pros' & cons'. I've gone through the [doc](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#theproducer) of Kafka and the [WSO2 MB](https://docs.wso2.com/display/MB310/WSO2+Message+Broker+Documentation) documentation. Are there any major differences when comparing one against the other? Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

- **Architecture**

*WSO2 MB*: Built by extending Apache Qpid code base. Also it uses apache zookeeper and apache cassandra.

*Apache Kafka*: 
Solution built from scratch.

- **Web Management Console**

*WSO2 MB*: Native Management Console

*Apache Kafka*: No native Management Console. But there is some open source options: https://github.com/yahoo/kafka-manager and https://github.com/claudemamo/kafka-web-console

- **Community**

*Apache Kafka*: used by giant companies checkout below
https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Powered+By

*WSO2 MB*: doesn't have proven use-cases in the market.

- **Protocols**

*WSO2 MB*: Support JMS, AMQP and MQTT

*Apache Kafka*: It has its own protocol which built over TCP http://kafka.apache.org/protocol.html Kafka built for high throughput and large scale message processing applications.

- **Client Libraries**

*Apache Kafka*:  https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Clients

*WSO2 MB*: Java

Comment: Although WSO2MB has been using Zookeeper and Cassandra in older versions, from version 3.0.0 onward it is using Hazelcast and RDBMS.

One more point I would add to architecture is WSO2MB is horizontally scalable, meaning you can create a cluster of MB nodes and distribute the load.